# Add SQL Results To A Dynamics CRM Report

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have some SQL that I've written that I ultimately want the results to appear on a Dashbord. I've saved it as a View in SQL Server, but have no idea where to begin to make Dynamics aware of that View, and accessing the data in a way that I can add it to a dashboard.

I've looked high and low, and haven't found any answers. Most are people saying that they are doing this sort of thing, and are having SQL logic issues.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert your view to a SSRS report which is stored in CRM (Workplace -> Reports).

[Create Reports for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Using SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx)

Once there, you can add the report to a dashboard.

[How to Display a Report in a Dashboard in Dynamics CRM 2011?](http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/archive/2011/10/27/how-to-display-a-report-in-a-dashboard-in-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx)

Comment: Unless you wanted to do something wacky like put it in a web resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SSRS report and put it onto the form:

http://mscrmshop.blogspot.sg/2012/02/step-by-step-tutorial-to-add-crm-report.html